# How to turn On gps programmatically from an Angular PWA application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

In my, Angular PWA application, I need to redirect the user to the Settings page of the device and user has to turn on GPS manually.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). Read how to create a [mcve]  before adding your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.geolocation`. This will automatically prompt to enable GPS.

```
 getPosition(): Promise<any>
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resp => {

          resolve({lng: resp.coords.longitude, lat: resp.coords.latitude});
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }
```

Comment: This is showing wrong coordinates. How can I only track device location instead of connecting to internet IP. just GPS in PWA ?

Comment: @NoobCoder The coordinates are not retreieved only retreived from IP address. Its completely up to the implementation of the browser to return coordinates for you. It does so using all kinds of data available to it to try to guess where you are. On pcs its going to be less precise, while on phones, gps will enable and return that.